# Insertion reflection code with local variables in Ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby, reflection, eval, yield

```
class Test
  def method
    a = 2
    b = 3
    yield
    c = 4
    a *= c
    a
  end

  def method_x
    method {}
  end

  def method_y
    method { a += b }
  end
end

test = Test.new
p test.method_x
p test.method_y
```

This above code doesn't work well.

```
$ ruby code.rb
8
code.rb:16:in `block in method_y': undefined local variable or method `b' for #<Test:0x007fe6da094890> (NameError)
    from code.rb:5:in `method'
    from code.rb:16:in `method_y'
    from code.rb:22:in `<main>'
```

I had expected that test.method_y returns 20.
I'd like to insert reflection code within a specific process.
But I don't know to use local variables on destination code block within reflection code.
Could you tell me how to use local variables or a good design?

Answer (score 1):

The block doesn't have access to the method variables.  You need to pass those variables into the block.

```
class Test
  def method
    a = 2
    b = 3
    a = yield(a,b) || a
    c = 4
    a *= c
    a
  end

  def method_x
    method {}
  end

  def method_y
    method { |x, y| x += y }
  end
end

test = Test.new
p test.method_x
p test.method_y
```

Since the block might return nil, the above code only moves the result of the block into `a` if it's not nil, otherwise it leaves `a` unchanged.

EDIT

It's also possible that you don't pass a block into a method... the block can be optional.

In which case you might want to do...

```
(a = yield(a,b) || a) if block_given?
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is the way, you can pass variables in the ruby code block:

```
class Test
  def method
    a = 2
    b = 3
    a = block_given? ? a : yield(a, b)
    c = 4
    a *= c
    a
  end

  def method_x
    method {}
  end

  def method_y
    method {|a,b| a += b }
  end
end

test = Test.new
p test.method_x
p test.method_y
```

The problem with your code is it doesn't modifies your local variable and the syntax is used wrong to pass variable in the code block. One useful link on how to use code block in ruby is [here](http://blog.codahale.com/2005/11/24/a-ruby-howto-writing-a-method-that-uses-code-blocks/).

Comment: The problem with this code is `method_x` will pass an empty block, so `a` becomes nil, and `a *= c` raises an exception. The implication of OP's question is that he would expect an empty block to leave `a` unchanged.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn: Point noted, completely agree, updated the answer accordingly

Comment: (ahem) I like your fix, but... in method_x a block IS given... it's an empty block, but it's present regardless and `block_given?` will return `true`. I think it's necessary to test if the block (if present) returns nil to make class Test bullet-proof.

Comment: block_given? and "a=yield(a,b)" are informative for me. Thanks a lot.